# Shell Script Error - ./check_disk.sh: line 9: [: Use: integer expression expected

Tags: bash, shell

Trying to get a simple alert when the disk is above 80

```bash
#! /usr/bin/bash -x
alert=80
df -H | awk '{print $5 " " $1}' | while read ouput;
  do
      usage=$(echo $ouput | awk '{print $1}'| cut -d'%' -f1)
      file_sys=$(echo $output | awk '{print $2}')
      echo $file_sys
      if [ $usage -ge $alert ]
      then
        echo "critical for $file_sys"
      fi
  done
```

Following is the Ouput with set -x:

```
+ '[' Use -ge 80 ']'
./check_disk.sh: line 8: [: Use: integer expression expected
```

Comment: `while read output; do` "do" is missing

Comment: Sorry, Missed it when I copied it. I get error same error after including do. 

#! /usr/bin/bash
alert=80

df -H | awk '{print $5 " " $1}' | while read ouput;
do
        usage=$(echo $ouput | awk '{print $1}'| cut -d'%' -f1)
        file_sys=$(echo $output | awk '{print $2}')
        echo $file_sys
        if [ $usage -ge $alert ]
        then
                echo "ciritcal for $file_sys"
        fi

done

Comment: The message meanst that either `usage` or `alert` is not an integral number. Run your script with `set -x` turn on. Also don't inform us about code changes you tried later in a comment (which is, as you for sure can see by yourself, hardly readable, but amend your question. There is a tiny _edit_ button below the question, which allows you to include such information afterwards.

Comment: Thank you, I've added the output to the question

Comment: It's saying `Use` isn't a number. That's a pretty obvious error, isn't it?

Comment: ...you need to tell awk to skip the header from `df`, or tell `df` not to _write_ a header.

Comment: Note that df is part of your operating system, not part of the shell, so it's different between platforms. Presumably whoever wrote the tutorial you're following was doing somewhere df didn't write a header when its output wasn't going to a TTY.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash

alert=89

while read usage file_sys
do
        usage=${usage//%/}
        echo "# $file_sys"
        if [ $usage -ge $alert ]
        then
                echo "  - ciritcal for $file_sys"
        fi
done < <(df --output="pcent,source"|sed '1d')
```

Or using only awk

```
awk -v alert="40" 'NR!=1 && $1>alert {print "ciritical for", $2}' <(df --output="pcent,source")
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you complete the task just with `awk`:

```
alert=90        # just for example
df -P | awk -v alert="$alert" 'NR>1 {
    print $1
    if ($5 > alert) printf "ciritical for %s (%s)\n", $1, $5
}'
```

Comment: Thank you, I'm a newbie to shell scripting and was practicing this example from the tutorial. Somehow it doesn't work for me. 
I'll try with your script.